How can I retrieve transactions of an address on a particular contract?
at the moment the only way I know is to get all the address signatures and then use getTransaction. But that is not efficient and I don't think it is the correct way to do it.
Any advice or solution?

It is the correct way to do it generally speaking. Some kinds of programs support special indexers, such as the ones provided by Helius or Shyft. You can also consider writing your own custom indexer if you find yourself querying past transactions a lot.

so there are no dedicated endpoints to do this?

Not as part of the standardized RPC interface, no.
